# ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5'

Tags: python, qt, webrtc

I am trying to get the script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48676566/grant-access-to-cam-mic-using-python-for-pyqt-webengine) to work on Raspberry Pi. I have tested it on Windows and Ubuntu and it works fine. But getting pyqt5 working on RPi seems to be a challenge. On Ubuntu the following works:

```
sudo apt-get python3.5
sudo pip3 install pyqt5
```

But this doesnt work on Pi as there is no pyqt5 package.

I have tried the below, but while it runs fine I dont think that actually creates python modules:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default pyqt5-dev pyqt5-dev-tools
```

I have tried the below, but it gives me "No files/directories in /tmp/pip-build-2rya72fo/python-qt5/pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)"

```
pip3 install python-qt5
```

What is the correct way to get pyqt5 working with Python on Raspberry Pi (Jessie)? I need pyqt5 for the WebEngine support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally a good idea is to do a search on the Pi.

`apt-cache search pyqt5`

Perhaps the command you need is

`sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`

I suggest you always preferentially use apt-get rather than pip.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't apt-get used to install programs rather than Python modules? How will python be aware of the install and where will the necessary python scripts install to?

Comment: Aha. I started with a fresh image of Jessie and this seemed to work. I can now import PyQt5 into python. I think the problem before was that I was trying to install python-pyqt5 instead of python3-pyqt5. I expect that also explains why the pip install failed. However now I get an error on one module: QtWebEngineWidgets. I will google that issue separately.